# Redis sentinel does not update IP addresses it is monitoring automatically

Tags: redis, kubernetes

For example, a Redis sentinel instance monitors a Redis shard made up of several Redis server instances (one master and several slaves per shard). I deployed a server instance as a container within a [Kubernetes pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/). IP address of the pod may change during some occasions such as after rolling update. This results in `failover-abort-no-good-slave` because the sentinel instance has obsolete server IP addresses.

How should the sentinel instance picks up the IP address change?

Setting up a hostname for the master and slaves does not work - the sentinel instance will convert the hostname (which is given during initiation) to IP address when overwriting `sentinel.conf` file.

Comment: What is causing the IP address change?

Comment: For my use case, each server instance is encapsulated within a Kubernetes pod. The pod IP address may change at some occasions (e.g., after rolling update). Let me update the question details.